Any manifold with fundamental group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ is orientable
I have enjoyed the construction of the rational circle found here, but I still have no clue on how to show that such a space, or any other with fundamental group $\mathbb{Q}$, must be orientable.
In this homework assignment a manifold $M$ is defined to be orientable if the bundle of antisymmetric -linear forms $\Lambda^n(M)$ is trivial. Equivalently, $\Lambda^n(M)$ admits a nowhere vanishing section.

If a manifold is non-orientable, then there is a non-trivial map from $\pi_1(M)$ to $\{\pm 1\}$, where $\gamma$ maps to the non-trivial element if there exists a frame whose parallel transport around $\gamma$ causes it to flip orientation. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ admits no non-trivial maps to the group of two elements, such a manifold must be orientable.

Alternative argument, which is really the same, a manifold is non-orientable iff its orientation double-cover is connected. Your manifold can't have a connected double-cover because it doesn't have an index two subgroup.

*cause its fundamental group doesn't have an index two subgroup (i can't edit the previous comment)
